# Vue.js - cannot add click event

Tags: onclick, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to add click event listener for DOM. All the scripts are bundled with webpack which compiles it to 1 large file.

This is my component:

```
<template>
    <div class="formchat-window">
        <a>test</a>
        <div class="title" v-on:click.self="toggle">Nevíte si rady? Zeptejte se!</div>
        <wp-formchat-screen v-if="windowActive"></wp-formchat-screen>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted () {
            console.log('mounted');

        },

        methods: {
            toggle(event) {
                alert('click on toggle');
                this.windowActive = !this.windowActive;
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                windowActive: false,
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    $color: red;

    .formchat-window {
        position: fixed;
        right: 10%;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 300px;
        z-index: 9999;
        .title {
            background: $color;
        }
    }
</style>
```

This is my main JS file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import FormChat from './FormChat'

import FormchatAnswer from './components/FormchatAnswer'
import FormchatEntry from './components/FormchatEntry'
import FormchatScreen from './components/FormchatScreen'
import FormchatWindow from './components/FormchatWindow'


window.Vue = Vue;


console.log('test');

Vue.component('WpFormchatAnswer', FormchatAnswer);
Vue.component('WpFormchatEntry', FormchatEntry);
Vue.component('WpFormchatScreen', FormchatScreen);
Vue.component('WpFormchatWindow', FormchatWindow);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#wp-formchat-vue-root',
    //render: h => h(FormChat)
});
```

However I did everything and compiler works perfectly, I cant register the click, so the method won't trigger.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your code work fine and click work fine. Look error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out. In the console, there was a warning about component name and main filename. I have renamed main file and the Vue started to work again.

Beware of ambigious naming :)